# How to connect to ArcGIS Server over the Internet using Visual Studio (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, esri, arcgis-server

I want to connect to an ArcGIS Server 10 web service and view a layer using esri:Map component. Is there any sample code available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Developing_with_ArcGIS_Server/0001000004q9000000/

and here you have an example on displaying a map hosted on a server
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Map_services/0001000002rm000000/